# undefined method `paginate' for #<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x000000046a9650>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx, will-paginate, ruby-1.9.3

I am using rails 3.2.13, sphinx server which is working fine, after I installed will_paginate gem pagination is not working.

Error is:

```
 NoMethodError in DashboardsController#search

undefined method `paginate' for #<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x000000046a9650>
app/controllers/dashboards_controller.rb:12:in `search'
```

This is the code for my Dashboard Cotroller

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController    
  def search
    query=[]
    query << "#{params[:property_listing]}" if(params[:property_listing]).present?
    query << "#{params[:property_type]}" if(params[:property_type]).present?
    query << "#{params[:city]}" if(params[:city]).present?
    query << "#{params[:sale_price]}" if(params[:sale_price]).present?
    @properties = Property.search("*#{query}*").paginate(:page=>params[:page], :per_page=>5)
    @json = @properties.to_gmaps4rails
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

search.html.erb

```
<% @properties.each do |property| %>
 //some codes which is working fine before using pagination
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate(@properties) %>
```

I have installed gem

```
gem 'will_paginate','>= 3.0.pre'
```

Result is not displaying, what mistake I did?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [pagination of Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#pagination) :

```
@properties = Property.search("*#{query}*", :page=>params[:page], :per_page=>5)
```